# sharepoint 2016 webpart can use in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016

I am new to share point development. Is this possible to use Share point 2016 web part can use in Share point 2013 version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify what web part ? It is custom web part developed by you ? Or is it out-of-box web part from SharePoint 2016 Gallery ? If developed by you - yes, you can. Just change Microsoft.Sharepoint dll-s references to 2013 version. And I think it would working. If web part from Gallery then I didn't know. May be no because it can use new SharePoint version dll-s inside its code and you cannot change it.

Comment: Thanks for your time, user10745346.                                                               
Web parts are developed in c#.Net with target version of framework so it doesn't matter what version of sharepoint.